# display: inline-block adds space to empty clear-div

Tags: html, css

I have some old code here where `<div class="clear">` elements where used to clear floating elements:

```
.teaser {
    background: lightblue;
    .text {
        background: green;
    }
    .clear {
        display: inline-block;
        width: 100%;
        clear: both;
    }
}
```

The problem ist, that the `display: inline-block;` adds some space to the box at the end. Now I know that that's a common problem, but I tried everything:

- `vertical-align: top;`(and `overflow: hidden;`)
- `height: 0;`
- `font-size: 0;`
- `line-height: 0;`
- `margin-bottom: -10px;`

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rJZBS/3/)

What did I miss?

Comment: Why don't you set it to "block"?

Comment: @JonasGrumann That would possibly change the behaviour of the clearfix on hunderts of parts of this webpage. So I have to stick with this for now.

Comment: ok, but for the next time I suggest you set it to block, it just makes more sense and you avoid the whole "inline-blocks add spaces" thing. I  also suggest you read this: http://www.quirksmode.org/blog/archives/2005/03/clearing_floats.html I usually clear my floats this way and never had big issues

Answer (score 0):

You can correct `display: inline-block` issues by adding either:

- A HTML comment between the elements
- A `margin-right: -4px;` to each element

Other than that I would recommend using the standard clearfix approach for clearing floats:

```
.clearfix:before,
.clearfix:after {
    content: " "; /* 1 */
    display: table; /* 2 */
}

.clearfix:after {
    clear: both;
}
```

Comment: As you can see in my example comments don't help here. A right margin doesnt help either because I get the additional space at the bottom.

Answer (score 0):

Add `<div class="clear">` just after ending tag. Like this-

```
<div class="teaser">
    <div class="content line_bottom">

        <h4>WM 2014 in Brasilien beginnt unter optimalen Bedingungen für Deutsches Team</h4>

        <div class="text">
          Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua.
        </div><div class="clear">
    </div>
</div>
```

Check your updated [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rJZBS/11/)

Comment: That doesn't work. You oversaw a brace in the CSS after the .teaser class: http://jsfiddle.net/rJZBS/12/

Answer (score 0):

As an inline-block float clearer might cause some problems, I suggest you go with the little overflow - clear trick. Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/rJZBS/5/

```
<div class="teaser">
    <div class="content line_bottom">
        <h4>Title</h4>

            <div class="text">
                Some text.
            </div>
        </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.teaser {
    background: lightblue;
    overflow: hidden;
    .text {
        background: green;
    }
}
```